# What is the difference between setHighlighted and setSelected in UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What is the difference between `setHighlighted` and `setSelected` in `UITableViewCell` ?

If I just want to not highlight a `cell` when a selection is made, Should I override `setHighlighter` or Just set the `selectionStyle` to `NONE`.

Answer (score 13):

`setHighlighted` will mark the object with a highlighted colour (or glow, depending on your settings) when the finger is touching down. On touch up, the highlight disappears and the object state returns to normal.

`setSelected` on the other hand, while similar, will be set on touch down, and will remain in the highlighted state until the next touch down event occurs.

What I think you want is to override `setHighlighted` (just return inside the method and don't call `super`), but more simply, you can just [set the cell's `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle).

Answer (score 3):

To not let the UITableView highlight the cell, implement and return NO in the tableView delegate method `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.